# How to apply javascript validations only to visible elements on HTML page,if i am using jQuery's .hide() and .show() methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my jQuery Code snippet.

```
$("#firstBankDetail").hide();
$("#secondBankDetail").hide();
$("#thirdBankDetail").hide();
$("#fourthBankDetail").hide();
$("#noOfBankDetails").change(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();

   if(value == 0) {
       $("#firstBankDetail").hide();
       $("#secondBankDetail").hide();
       $("#thirdBankDetail").hide();
       $("#fourthBankDetail").hide();
   }
   else if(value == 1) {
       $("#firstBankDetail").show();
       $("#secondBankDetail").hide();
       $("#thirdBankDetail").hide();
       $("#fourthBankDetail").hide();  
   }
   else if(value == 2) {
       $("#firstBankDetail").show();
       $("#secondBankDetail").show();
       $("#thirdBankDetail").hide();
       $("#fourthBankDetail").hide(); 
   }
   else if(value == 3){
       $("#firstBankDetail").show();
       $("#secondBankDetail").show();
       $("#thirdBankDetail").show();
       $("#fourthBankDetail").hide();  
   }
   else if(value == 4){
       $("#firstBankDetail").show();
       $("#secondBankDetail").show();
       $("#thirdBankDetail").show();
       $("#fourthBankDetail").show();
   }

});
```

So when body is loaded all the div's are hidden . `#noOfBankDetails` is a dropdown `<select/>` element. Based on its values the divs are hidden or shown. I have completed the javascript validations for all the div's.

Now i face an issue that validation fails for those div's those are hidden too. 
Say if only `#firstBankDetail` is visible even then validation will fail for child elements of `#secondBankDetail` , `#thirdBankDetail` and `#fourthBankDetail`.

Pseudo code of what i want to achieve is

```
IF `#firstBankDetail` Visible
Apply validations of `#firstBankDetail` only
IF `#firstBankDetail` and `#secondBankDetail` visible
Apply validations of `#firstBankDetail` and `#secondBankDetail` only
```

How can i achieve it using javascript  ?

Comment: You could use jQuery's `is(':visible')`  http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

```
$('#firstBankDetail:visible')
```

If your validation method was simply `validate()`, you'd use:

```
$('#firstBankDetail:visible').validate();
```

To apply the validation on *all* of your visible elements at once you'd look to the parent of the `#firstBankDetail`, `#secondBankDetail`, etc. So for instance if your HTML looked like this:

```html
<div id="parent">
    <input id="firstBankDetail"/>
    <input id="secondBankDetail"/>
</div>
```

To call the `validate()` method on all visible elements within the parent, you could simply use this:

```
$('#parent').children(':visible').validate();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However what if i want to do it using javascript only ? No jQuery.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh the code you posted up is riddled with jQuery and you've tagged jQuery in your question. Are you sure you don't want to use jQuery? jQuery is JavaScript, after all.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh if you're already using jQuery then there's not much reason not to use it for things like this.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh on StackOverflow you can flag comments by hovering over them and clicking on the flag icon that appears on the left. When a moderator deletes Joe's comments it will look like that comment was aimed at me, so figured I'd point it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
$("#firstBankDetail,#secondBankDetail,#thirdBankDetail,#fourthBankDetail").hide();
$("#noOfBankDetails").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == 0) {
       $("#firstBankDetail,#secondBankDetail,#thirdBankDetail,#fourthBankDetail").hide();
    }
    else if(value == 1) {
       $("#firstBankDetail").show();
       $("#secondBankDetail,#thirdBankDetail,#fourthBankDetail").hide();
    }
    else if(value == 2) {
       $("#firstBankDetail,#secondBankDetail").show();
       $("#thirdBankDetail,#fourthBankDetail").hide(); 
    }
    else if(value == 3){
       $("#firstBankDetail,#secondBankDetail,#thirdBankDetail").show();
       $("#fourthBankDetail").hide();  
    }
    else if(value == 4){
       $("#firstBankDetail,#secondBankDetail,#thirdBankDetail,#fourthBankDetail").show();
    }
});
```

Apply a class **bankDetail** to your fields **#firstBankDetail,#secondBankDetail,#thirdBankDetail,#fourthBankDetail**

```
//add this code in your script
$(".bankDetail:visible").validate();
```